# Finding users near other user

Tags: algorithm

what algorithms should I explore to implement a feature which lets a user find other user located near him , the latitude and the longitudes of all the user are known in advance and are fixed [not dynamic].
Also i believe that there should be a better way to store such data then simply storing the lat , long of the user against his user id in a  database.What are the efficient ways to handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just finding close points, all you need is a simple circular bounding radius, which you could adjust or favor logarithmically toward the center. Of course, you would want to avoid doing this over the whole data set for every query. Generally, in addition to lat/lon you would break the map down into quadrants that you know you can ignore off the bat. -- just make sure if your area of interest is marginal, to also query the neighboring quadrant. That is have a link table for fetching only rows in that quadrant.

Once you've reduced by quadrant. Using the most rudimentary geometry:

1) Eliminate a large portion of your data with a simple bounding box.

pseudocode:

```
 DistanceLat = abs( P2lat - P1lat);
 DistanceLon = abs( P2lon - P1lat)
```

2) Do Pythagorean theorem to see if point falls withing radius. Within the reduced data set (a2+b2 =c2)

```
Distance = Sqrt( DistanceLat * DistanceLat + DisanceLon * DistanceLon)
if ( Distance < radius) keep the data
```

Comment: yes, this is more similar to an OBB tree often used in physics simulation. Closest point is just taking it a step farther.

Answer (score 1):

**[MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)** (and others) now support [**spatial indexing.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_index)

And if your database can do [**spatial queries**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_query) you don't need to implement any part of the algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a k-D tree for a [nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

Comment: You don't need the nearest neighbor. That is computationally expensive and would only be used in the case that optimal point reduction has already been performed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main classes of datastructures for spatial search:

- spatial partition trees (like the [k-D tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree))
- overlapping bounding box trees (like the [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree))

If you want an overwhelmingly complete answer to your question, check out Hanan Samet's book, *Foundations of Multidimensional and Metric Data Structures*